# How to Implement Semaphores in iOS Application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, semaphore

Is it possible to implement Counting Semaphore in ios application?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
There are quite a few synchronization tools available:

- @synchronized
- NSLock
- NSCondition
- NSConditionLock
- GCD semaphores
- pthread locks
- ...

I'd suggest reading "[Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH1-SW1)" and asking something more specific.

Comment: @synchonized is my fav. Use it with a global object like a static NSNumber if there is no obvious object to block on. Sticking to one semaphore model will likely help with readability, etc.

Comment: Synchronizing on a global object is a bad idea. You don't know if any other code might also be synchronizing on it so you expose yourself to risk of deadlock. Always synchronize on something with limited visibility that is explicitly for the task at hand. Also, never synchronize on self; again, you don't know what else might be using the same object.

Answer (score 8):

Like this:

```
dispatch_semaphore_t sem = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

[self methodWithABlock:^(id result){
    //put code here
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);

    [self methodWithABlock:^(id result){
        //put code here
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sem);
    }];
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sem, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Credit http://www.g8production.com/post/76942348764/wait-for-blocks-execution-using-a-dispatch

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to find a native IOS object to do this but it works just fine using the C library:

```
#import "dispatch/semaphore.h"
...
dispatch_semaphore_t activity;
...
activity = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
...
dispatch_semaphore_signal(activity);
...
dispatch_semaphore_wait(activity, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift 3** you can use a `DispatchSemaphore`.

```
// initialization
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: initialValue)

// wait, decrement the semaphore count (if possible) or wait until count>0
semaphore.wait()

// release, increment the semaphore count
semaphore.signal()
```